# What is the best configuration for UniversalmageLoader

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, large-files, universal-image-loader

I want to load large images from a local source (with the "file://" tag) for a gridview like the default phone gallery application.

I have tested many configurations and nothing does what I want...

Either I have an OutOfMemoryException or the list lag hugely.

Here's how I currently initialize them :

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
    // Determine cache memory size
    int memoryCacheSize;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
        memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024; // 1/8 of app memory limit 
    } else {
        memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Imageloader.memoryCacheSize="+ memoryCacheSize);
    }

    // Configure the image loader
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .build();

    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

And my adapter :

```
private ImageLoader mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
private DisplayImageOptions mOptions  = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: There is no best config. It depends on context. What size(in pixels) of images do need to show? How much of them?

Comment: It's to make an application like the gallery with a gridview with 4 items per line, each items is 75dp (loaded by UniversalImageLoader), so for images of any size and an indeterminate amount.